# Time out in Roads and Libraries on HackerRack

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I've been working on this HackerRank problem for some time now, and I can't seem to understand why my code is timing out for large input sizes. I've implemented the adjacency list as a Hash map to cut down time, and have been using a stack for my DFS, as is standard to optimize it's run time. My basic strategy here is to use DFS to remove a group of connected node, and continue doing that until there are none left (my DFS removes nodes as they are reached), the problem is there are generally ~80,000 disconnected parts per graph *after* I take out the single nodes with no neighbors (so DFS is called 80,000 times). Is there any particularly better strategy here?

```
  static int numDisconnected(HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> adj)  {
    int result = 0;
    List<Integer> iter = new ArrayList<>(adj.keySet());
    for (int k : iter) {
      if (adj.get(k).size() == 0)  {
        adj.remove(k);
        result++;
      }
    }
    HashMap<Integer,Boolean> explored = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : adj.keySet())  {
      explored.put(i,false);
    }
    while (!adj.keySet().isEmpty())  {
      result++;
      depthFirstSearch(adj,explored);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

As a point of reference, my code takes about 1.5 seconds to run on my machine for a ~2MB file input.

Comment: May I suggest you do some profiling and narrow the offending code down to 10 lines or less.  If you're still stuck after doing that, you can come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @JoeC I'll do that now

Comment: One observation: the keys in all your `HashMap`s are consecutive integers, so an array is probably more efficient. (The HackerRank challenge uses 1-based indices for cities, so be sure to subtract one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, what you're doing is close, `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` is a good data structure for this task.
But you're doing redundant work by both keeping an `explored` list and deleting from the adjacency map in `numDisconnected` and in `depthFirstSearch` (in your earlier version of the question). Either of these should be enough to implement depth first search.

I tweaked your algorithm with not removing from adj, changing `explored` to  boolean[] and using that to explore a disconnected component, and to find the next node to start a DFS from when a component is done.

It passed, no need for the preprocessing step of removing unconnected nodes.

(Sorry for paraphrasing instead of posting code, but I'd rather not spoil it)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your original code (in the first revision of this question), I replaced those `HashMap`s with `ArrayList`s, used a `HashSet` for `explored`, inlined the `depthFirstSearch` (just for simplicity, not performance), and got rid of a couple steps that felt like premature optimization (removing nodes with no neighbors, early return in the main loop).

This passes all the tests in the [Roads and Libraries challenge on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/world-codesprint-8/challenges/torque-and-development/problem):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    static long cost(long cLib, long cRoad, ArrayList<List<Integer>> g, int gSize)  {
        if (cLib <= cRoad)  {
            return cLib * (long)gSize;
        }
        int discon = numDisconnected(g);
        return (cRoad * (gSize - discon)) + (cLib * discon);
    }

    static int numDisconnected(ArrayList<List<Integer>> adj)  {
        int result = 0;
        HashSet<Integer> explored = new HashSet<>();
        int length = adj.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (!explored.contains(i)) {
                Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
                stack.push(i);
                while (!stack.empty()) {
                    int curr = stack.pop();
                    explored.add(curr);
                    for (int neighbor : adj.get(curr)) {
                        if (!explored.contains(neighbor)) {
                            stack.push(neighbor);
                        }
                    }
                }

                result += 1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int q = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++){
            int nCities = in.nextInt();
            ArrayList<List<Integer>> adj = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(nCities);
            for (int i = 0; i < nCities; i++) {
                adj.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            }
            int nRoads = in.nextInt();
            long cLib = in.nextLong();
            long cRoad = in.nextLong();
            for (int i = 0; i < nRoads; i++) {
                int city_1 = in.nextInt() - 1;
                int city_2 = in.nextInt() - 1;
                adj.get(city_1).add(city_2);
                adj.get(city_2).add(city_1);
            }
            System.out.println(cost(cLib, cRoad, adj, nCities));
        }
    }
}
```